# Which hashing algorithm generates alphanumeric output?

Tags: hash

I am looking for an hashing algorithm that generates alphanumeric output. I did few tests with MD5 , SHA3 etc and they produce hexadecimal output.

Example:

Input: HelloWorld

Output[sha3_256]: 92dad9443e4dd6d70a7f11872101ebff87e21798e4fbb26fa4bf590eb440e71b

The 1st character in the above output is 9. Since output is in HEX format, maximum possible values are [0-9][a-f]

I am trying to achieve maximum possible values for the 1st character. [0-9][a-z][A-Z]

Any ideas would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: they produce binary values, the hex is just a way of representing it.

Comment: Your alphabet [0-9][a-z][A-Z] is a 62 character alphabet. If you would accept two more characters, + and /, you would have the standard base-64 alphabet and you could use a base-64 encoder that is almost certainly included in whatever language library you like to write programs in.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs njzk2 and  
President James K. Polk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where MD5 computes a 128bit hash and SHA256 a 256bit hash, the output they provide is nothing more than a 128, respectively 256 long binary number. In short, that are a lot of zero's and ones. In order to use a more human-friendly representation of binary-coded values, Software developers and system designers use hexadecimal numbers, which is a representation in base(16). For example, an 8-bit byte can have values ranging from 00000000 to 11111111 in binary form, which can be conveniently represented as 00 to FF in hexadecimal.

You could convert this binary number into a base(32) if you want. This is represented using the characters "A-Z2-7". Or you could use base(64) which needs the characters "A-Za-z0-9+/". In the end, it is just a representation.

There is, however, some practical use to base(16) or hexadecimal. In computer lingo, a byte is 8 bits and a word consists of two bytes (16 bits). All of these can be comfortably represented hexadecimally as *2<sup>8</sup> = 2<sup>4</sup>×2<sup>4</sup> = 16×16*. Where *2<sup>8</sup> = 2<sup>5</sup>×2<sup>3</sup> = 32×8*. Hence, in base(32), a byte is not cleanly represented. You already need 5 bytes to have a clean base(32) representation with 8 characters. That is not comfortable to deal with on a daily basis.